# How to check if a user has stopped typing in an input field?

Tags: javascript, input, socket.io, indicator

I have an indicator that notifies users when another user is typing by looking for a keypress on an input box. However, if the user removes what they were typing, the indicator still shows other users that they're still typing. How can I alter this to remove the indicator when the input field is empty.

The indicator will disappear when the message is sent, by setting `istyping` to an empty string. I'm not sure how to utilise this to detect an empty input field.

```
var message = document.getElementById('messagebox');
var istyping = document.getElementById('istyping');

message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    socket.emit('typing', {
        user: user || 'Anonymous'
    })
})

socket.on('typing', function(data){
    istyping.innerHTML = '<p><i>'+ data.user +" is typing..."+'</p></i>';
})
```

Comment: One way to do it would be to use setInterval in a wrapper function to repeatedly check the value of the input field once an input has been made, and return out of the function if Enter is pressed or the input goes back to being empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use setTimeout() to do it.

Example:

```
var message  = document.getElementById('messagebox');
var istyping = document.getElementById('istyping');
var timeout  = setTimeout(function(){}, 0);


message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout); /// clear timeout if user is typing
  istyping.innerHTML = 'User is typing';
  timeout = setTimeout(function() 
    { istyping.innerHTML = '' }, 1000 /// Time in milliseconds
)}
)
```

This basically says that an user is not typing if a key isn't pressed after X milliseconds. You can check out it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n2k0x9r6/)

Comment: I can see from the fiddle that it works... I just don't understand how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout for this. As soon as the user inputs any character in the input field set a new timeout and clear the older one. You can set the time as per your preference.

```
var message = document.getElementById('messagebox');
var istyping = document.getElementById('istyping');
var typingInterval = 3000;
var typingTimer;
message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
clearInterval(typingTimer);
typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, typingInterval)
socket.emit('typing', {
    user: user || 'Anonymous'
  })
})

function doneTyping () {
    socket.emit('doneTyping',{
        user: user || 'Anonymous'
    })
}
socket.on('typing', function(data){
    istyping.innerHTML = '<p><i>'+ data.user +" is typing..."+'</p></i>';
})
socket.on('doneTyping', function(data){
    istyping.innerHTML = '';
})
```

This solution will remove the is Typing... text from UI if user does not type anything for 3 seconds

Comment: This is basically what I did and it works - thanks!